# Can I query the current scope(s)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, named-scope

My collections model has a scope like this

```
scope :got, -> { where(status: 'Got') }
```

I have a link to an index as follows

```
<%= user_collections_path(@user, got: true) %>
```

Thanks to the has_scope gem that creates an index of the user's collections where the status: is 'Got'. the path is

> users/user1/collections?got=true

In that index view I want to be able to write something like

```
<% if status: 'Got' %>
   You have these ones
<% end %>
```

But no matter how I write it I can't seem to query the scope that was passed in the link. Is there a standard way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as following:

```
<% if params[:got].to_s == 'true' %>
   You have these ones
<% end %>
```

But this forces you to use `true` as value for `params[:got]`. Maybe this is better:

```
<% if params[:got].present? %>
   You have these ones
<% end %>
```

But this will work with params like:

- `users/user1/collections?got=true`,
- `users/user1/collections?got=false`,
- `users/user1/collections?got=NOPE`,
- etc.

---

Actually, the `has_scope` gem provides a method `current_scopes` that returns a hash (key = scope, value = value given to the scope) in the corresponding views. You should be able to do like this:

```
<% if current_scopes[:got].present? %>
   You have these ones
<% end %>
```

Comment: That's great. I didn't realise the scope became a param when passed but that makes total sense. Is the current_scopes method any better as code? Both work a treat. Thank you so much.

Comment: The `current_scopes` method is better in your case. It is just a getter of the `@current_scopes` instance variable of the class including the module `HasScope` (`has_scope/lib/has_scope.rb:182`)

Comment: Great. Using that then. Now I need to work out if I can pass those scopes on in the search form on the index page. Can't write another question yet though. THanks so so much.

Comment: Added new question here :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24436568/pass-current-scopes-on-to-search