# Pass current_scopes on to search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, named-scope, has-scope

I'm using the very helpful [has_scope](https://github.com/plataformatec/has_scope) gem.
I have an index page created by passing scopes in a link.

```
<%= user_collections_path(@user, got: true) %>
```

On that index page I can query the current_scopes.

I have a pretty standard ransack search form on that page but using it returns results without any scopes.

How can I pass the current_scopes on to the search? I tried using a hidden field but couldn't get it to work. I thought if I could pass the scopes in a link I ought to be able to pass them in a form but after googling I'm not sure that is true.

**Search form**

```
<%= search_form_for @search, :html => {:method => :post} do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :name_or_miniature_name_cont, class: "span3" %>
    <%= f.submit "Search", class: "btn" %>
<% end %>
```

**Index method**

```
 def index
    @user = User.find_by_username(params[:user_id])
    @search = apply_scopes(@user.collections).search(params[:q])
    @search.sorts = 'created_at desc' if @search.sorts.empty?  
    @collections = @search.result.paginate(page: params[:page])
 end
```

Comment: Hey @Ossie did you ever solve this? I have the same requirement at the moment

Comment: No joy. Frustrating.

Comment: Hey mate was having the same issue, and have been able to solve it with the new Ransack functionality, check my answer and let me know if it helps.

Comment: I can't test it just now but I will and thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Using the new functionality in Ransack 1.6+ you can introduce scopes into your Ransack search, but first you need to whitelist them, like so:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :active, ->(boolean = true) { where(active: boolean) }
  scope :salary_gt, ->(amount) { where('salary > ?', amount) }

      # `ransackable_scopes` by default returns an empty array
      # i.e. no class methods/scopes are authorized.
      # For overriding with a whitelist array of *symbols*.
      #
   def self.ransackable_scopes(auth_object = nil)
    [:active, :salary_gt]
   end
end
```

Then you can trigger them like this:

```
Employee.ransack({ active: true, hired_since: '2013-01-01' })

Employee.ransack({ salary_gt: 100_000 }, { auth_object: current_user })
```

You can also add them to your search_form_for as per normal.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could store / retrieve the data from the current `session` rather than to put it into a url parameter.

To quote a comment on [an issue](https://github.com/plataformatec/has_scope/issues/6):

> This is the reason has_scope supports :default, so you can give a proc
>   a retrieve the value from session:
>
> `has_scope :degree, :default => proc { |c| c.session[:some_value] }`

Comment: Ok. Sounds good. Not quite sure how to implement that. When would the scopes be expunged from the session? Slightly worried about scope pileup.

Comment: @WorldOfProper Until you overwrite the value or it expires.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass current scopes in the action url:

```
<%= search_form_for @search, url: search_people_path(current_scopes), do |f| %>
```